# Sharing visited urls between multiple spiders in scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, scrapyd

I am using scrapyd to run multiple spiders as jobs across the same domain. I assumed scrapy had a hashtable of visited urls that it shared and co-ordinated with other spiders when it crawled. When I create instances of the same spider by

```
curl http://localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project=projectname -d spider=spidername.
```

it rather crawls the same urls and duplicate data is being scraped. Has someone dealt with a similar problem before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice would be to try to divide the site into multiple `start_urls`. Then, [you can pass the different values for `start_urls` to each spider](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scrapy-users/rELsP8R8VXk).

If you want to get particularly fancy, (or if the pages you want to crawl change on a regular basis) you could create a spider that crawls the sitemap, divides the links up into `n` cunks, then starts `n` other spiders to actually crawl the site...